# busybox shows for `type -a ls` command links to /bin/ls instead of ls

Tags: command-line, execute-command, busybox, ash

I did some modifications in busybox source. Then I executed some commands as below with output:

```
root@sai ~$ ls
1D_bar            barcode_serial    insmod            pam_aut
root@sai ~$ /bin/busybox ls
hiiiii.. hello..
Credentials accepted.
Password:
Account is valid.
Authenticated
pam ret: 0
applet name: ls
1D_bar            barcode_serial    insmod            pam_aut
```

Here I check the inode numbers also, both are same.

```
root@sai ~$ ls  -i  /bin/busybox
7976 /bin/ls
root@sai ~$ ls  -i  /bin/ls
7976 /bin/busybox
```

I checked the soft link also. ls linked to `/bin/busybox` only.

Is their anything else to check? and one more is

```
root@sai ~$ type -a ls
/bin/ls
root@sai ~$ type -a cd
cd
root@sai ~$
```

getting different output for *$ type -a* command.

Please help me to solve the issue for getting same output.

Comment: What does `type -a ls` report?

Comment: `root@sai ~$ type -a ls`
`/bin/ls`         that's it, nothing else

Comment: Busybox ash should report `ls is ls`, not `ls is /bin/ls`. What does `lsof | grep -w $$` report? Edit your question to add the details.

Comment: `root@sai ~$ lsof | grep -w $$`
`731 /bin/busybox /dev/ttyGS0`
`731 /bin/busybox /dev/ttyGS0`
`731 /bin/busybox /dev/ttyGS0`
`731 /bin/busybox /dev/tty`
`root@sai ~$ `
getting this information

Comment: What I have to do for `type -a ls` gets the output for `ls` ? is anything need to modify in busybox source ?

Comment: Again: edit your question to add the details.

Comment: what the difference between those both ls and /bin/ls for type -a command output ?